# How to get floating-point literals's locations in source code in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, parsing, floating-point

I would like to write a function whose input is a piece of C/C++ code,
and whose output is the exact of locations of floating-point
literals.  Preferred implementation languages are Java or Python, although
this question is language-agnostic.

Example input program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main() {
   float x = 10.3;
   int y = 28;
   printf("The float value : %f\n", x);
   printf("The sum of float and int variable : %f\n", (x+y));
   return 0;
}
```

The output should be something like `4, 13-16` indicating the line and offset location of the float literal 10.3. The reason I need to get this location is to
automatically transfer the literal to another one for the purpose of
developing a bug analysis and tracking tool.

Any idea how we can precisely get the locations?

I tried to apply a simple regular expression to capture decimals like
"10.3" but it would also capture floats in comments, like
// APACHE-common-2.0, and strings, like printf( "%2.5g", x);, also
regular expression-based solutions would miss floats in "double x=0;".

Comment: The examples you give would be detected with regular expressions for `float <identifier> = <float-value>;` and `double <identifier> = <float-value>;`. You can reject comments by matching `//`, and pseudo-floats in formats by matching and rejecting `%<float-value>`. This is not bulletproof, but a low-cost solution.

Comment: Thanks! With regular expressions, can I also reject those in /* */ ?

Comment: It will mainly depend on how manic you and your colleagues are.  If you write comments with the start or end token split across lines because you've used backslash-newline to splice them together, or other such insanities, then writing regexes for comments is painful.  If you don't play such games, it's doable.

Comment: `double x=0;` does not contain a floating point literal, but an integer which is implicitly converted to a `double` (even though most compilers will be able to do that at compile time). If you wanted to catch implicit conversions as well, then `2*x` would also be such a case, if `x` is a `double`.

Comment: Even C has `typedef`. There's no reason to assume that the token used is _literally_ `float`. Heck, in C++ you really expect `auto x = 10.3` these days. Parsing C++ with a regex is a bit harder than trying to parse HTML with a regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be looking for something like [Kythe](https://kythe.io/), it is a tool Google build to index and search their source code.

As I understand it (I have only seen a presentation, not worked with the tool myself), it is build on top of LLVM(?) and uses the compiler to build and extract a graph of the code. This then enables somebody to search for f.ex. places where a specific function is called - not just functions that are named the same, but call-sites that actually link to "this specific definition".

Comment: I suspect you'd want the Clang front-end more than LLVM, but the two projects are related.